# Can cabal not un-install packages?

Tags: haskell

`cabal help` shows thers isnot "uninstall" option.

then what's the best way to uninstall the packages installed by cabal ?

```
% cabal update
% cabal install mighttpd2
```

mighttpd2 is installed successfully. However the ghc-pkg cannot find & unregister it:

```
% ghc-pkg list | grep -i might
% ghc-pkg unregister mighttpd2
ghc-pkg: cannot find package mighttpd2
```

Sincerely!

```
>find .cabal | grep -i mighttp
.cabal/share/doc/mighttpd2-2.3.3
.cabal/share/doc/mighttpd2-2.3.3/LICENSE
.cabal/share/mighttpd2-2.3.3
.cabal/share/mighttpd2-2.3.3/sample.conf
.cabal/share/mighttpd2-2.3.3/sample.route
.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/mighttpd2
.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/mighttpd2/2.3.3
.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/mighttpd2/2.3.3/mighttpd2-2.3.3.tar.gz

>ghc-pkg list | grep -i package\.conf
 /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.3/package.conf.d:
 /home/sw2wolf/.ghc/i386-freebsd-7.0.3/package.conf.d:
```

So ".cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org" cannot be seen by ghc-pkg.

Comment: You can't 'uninstall', you can only unregister it: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install#How_can_I_uninstall_packages.3F

Comment: My guess is a user mis-match; does `cabal list mightppd2` say it's installed?  Are you sure you're using the same user (i.e. sw2wolf) to install the package as doing the ghc-pkg stuff?

Comment: I am sure it is the same user.  `1cabal list mightppd2` reports "No matches found."

Answer (score 5):

you might not have the Cabal path as part of your GHC path.

#### step 1

First, try to find out what your GHC package path is,

```
ghc-pkg list
    # displays stuff like "/home/username/.../package.conf.d"
```

then, make sure the one Cabal is writing to is active. For me, Cabal adds packages to

```
/home/username/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.0.4/package.conf.d
```

#### step 2

If there is no such directory on your system, see what Cabal's writing.

```
strace -f -o trace.txt cabal install mighttpd2
grep "package\.cache" trace.txt
```

then add the package path to this system environment variable

```
export GHC_PACKAGE_PATH=NEWPATH:/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.3/package.conf.d
```

try again, if it doesn't work proceed to step 3

#### step 3

look in that directory and see if there's a file like

```
mighthttpd2-version-LONGHASHCODE.conf
```

if it's there, then you probably need to recache

```
ghc-pkg recache --user
```

Comment: ghc-pkg list | grep -i package
    /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.3/package.conf.d:
    /home/sw2wolf/.ghc/i386-freebsd-7.0.3/package.conf.d:

Answer (score 2):

The GHC package system is not used for executables, and the `mighttpd2` package only builds executables. To uninstall it, simply remove the two executables (`mighty` and `mkindex`) and the two data files (`sample.conf` and `sample.route`) listed in the package's cabal file. You can find which directories these files were installed to by perusing cabal's config file in `~/.cabal/config`.

Comment: ok, howver the packages depended by mighty is difficult to remove. As the `cabal install might*` installed many packages i dont need before.

Comment: That's true. There's currently no tool support for tracking _why_ a package was installed (and therefore no tool support for highlighting packages that no longer have a reason for being installed). Sorry about that.