# How can I uninstall a version of a Cabal package?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

Happstack Lite is breaking on me because it's getting blaze-html version 0.5 and it wants version 0.4.  Cabal says that *both* versions 0.4.3.4 and 0.5.0.0 are installed.  I want to remove the 0.5.0.0 and use just the older version.  But cabal does not have an "uninstall" command, and when I try `ghc-pkg unregister --force blaze-html`, `ghc-pkg` says my command has been ignored.

What do I do?

**UPDATE**: *Don't believe it*.  Although `ghc-pkg` claims to ignore the command, the command *isn't* ignored.  And with Don Stewart's accepted answer you can remove exactly the version you wish to eliminate.

Comment: `ghc-pkg list blaze-html` ?  Are you sure you're running it as the right user?  Maybe explicitly state the version to be unregistered?

Comment: @ivanm thanks for asking.  Turns out `ghc-pkg` *lied* to me!

Comment: Sort of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252193/can-cabal-not-un-install-packages, but I'm reluctant to flag it because this one's better :)

Comment: [cabal-delete](https://github.com/iquiw/cabal-delete) is pretty nice for finding and removing orphaned packages.

Comment: @Tobu What about `cabal-uninstall` [mentioned in answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14248672/94687)? Is cabal-delete more powerful? Can it work with a cabal sandbox (will `cabal exec -- cabal-delete` work correctly and delete packages from the sandbox)? Why not make this an answer, too? It looks like a nice tool.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can `ghc-pkg unregister` a specific version, like so:

```sh
$ ghc-pkg unregister --force regex-compat-0.95.1
```

That should be sufficient.

Comment: once unregistered, are there any files lying around somewhere that should be pruned?

Comment: Comments on other places mention that ghc-pkg leaves folders around?

Comment: have a look in your `~/.cabal/` folder for information about where pkgs and binaries are

Answer (score 23):

If you are outside a sandbox:

```sh
ghc-pkg unregister --force regex-compat-0.95.1
```

If you are inside a [cabal sandbox](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes):

```sh
cabal sandbox hc-pkg -- unregister attoparsec --force
```

The first `--` is the argument separator for `hc-pkg`. This runs `ghc-pkg` in a sandbox aware manner.

Answer (score 20):

There is also the [cabal-uninstall](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-uninstall) package which provides a `cabal-uninstall` command.  It unregisters the package and deletes the folder.  It is worth mentioning though that it passes `--force` to `ghc-pkg unregister` so it can break other packages.

Comment: `cabal uninstall` results in `cabal: unrecognised command: uninstall (try --help)`

Comment: @StevenShaw - The link I provided goes to a hackage package that you need to install in order to use. I would recommend Don's answer, that is what I use.

Comment: What about [cabal-delete](https://github.com/iquiw/cabal-delete) from a comment above by @Tobu? Is it better or more powerful than cabal-uninstall?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a shell script I use to uninstall a package. It supports multiple installed versions of GHC and also wipes relevant files (but is provided without warranty, don't blame me if you hose your installation!)

```bash
#!/bin/bash -eu
# Usage: ./uninstall.sh [--force | --no-unregister] pkgname-version

# if you set VER in the environment to e.g. "-7.0.1" you can use
# the ghc-pkg associated with a different GHC version
: ${VER:=}

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]
then
        echo "Usage: $0 [--force | --no-unregister] pkgname-version"
        exit 1
fi

if [ "$1" == "--force" ]
then force=--force; shift; # passed to ghc-pkg unregister
else force=
fi

if [ "$1" == "--no-unregister" ]
then shift # skip unregistering and just delete files
else
        if [ "$(ghc-pkg$VER latest $1)" != "$1" ]
        then
                # full version not specified: list options and exit
                ghc-pkg$VER list $1; exit 1
        fi
        ghc-pkg$VER unregister $force $1
fi

# wipe library files
rm -rfv -- ~/.cabal/lib/$1/ghc-$(ghc$VER --numeric-version)/

# if the directory is left empty, i.e. not on any other GHC version
if rmdir -- ~/.cabal/lib/$1 
then rm -rfv -- ~/.cabal/share/{,doc/}$1 # then wipe the shared files as well
fi
```

Comment: I just tried this on Mac and it does not seem to work.