# Serialize a data type defined with type classes

Tags: haskell

I need to serialize a `DAWG` (provided by [this library)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dawg-0.11/docs/Data-DAWG-Dynamic.html) to a bytestring. As I saw in the documentation that there is an instance `(Ord b, Binary b) => Binary (DAWG a b)` which seems to provide support for this, I tried directly to use `encode`:

```
import qualified Data.DAWG.Dynamic as Dawg
import qualified Data.Binary as Bin

Bin.encode $ Dawg.fromList [("foo",1),("bar",2)]
```

But GHC complains that there is `no instance for (Bin.Binary (Dawg.DAWG Char b0))`. I get the point that it is necessary to tell GHC what data types the graph contains, but then, how is it done? And if I'm wrong, what am I supposed to do instead?

*Edit* : 
Stack trace for `Bin.encode $ Dawg.fromList [("foo"::String,1::Int),("bar",2)]`:

```
<interactive>:19:1:
    No instance for (Bin.Binary (Dawg.DAWG Char Int))
      arising from a use of `Bin.encode'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Bin.Binary (Dawg.DAWG Char Int))
    In the expression: Bin.encode
    In the expression:
      Bin.encode
      $ Dawg.fromList [("foo" :: String, 1 :: Int), ("bar", 2)]
        In an equation for `it':
        it
          = Bin.encode
            $ Dawg.fromList [("foo" :: String, 1 :: Int), ("bar", 2)]
```

Comment: Without the complete error I can't be sure, but probably you're being bitten because `1` and `2` are polymorphic. Give one of them a type signature (e.g. `:: Int`) and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried to `Bin.encode $ Dawg.fromList [("foo",1::Int),("bar",2::Int)]`? I think `Binary` needs a concrete type in order to automatically serialize numbers.

Comment: I just tried this, but GHC still complains (though it know recognizes the graph type to be `Dawg.DAWG Char Int`).

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going on without seeing the error... Maybe you have `OverloadedStrings` enabled? What about `Bin.encode $ Dawg.fromList [("foo"::String,1::Int),("bar",2)]`?

Comment: @doukremt, I can't reproduce your error. Are you just doing what you wrote? Do you have any additional code?

Comment: @doukremt: I also can't reproduce. I have a file with the imports you have above and the line `test = Bin.encode $ Dawg.fromList [("foo"::String,1::Int),("bar",2)]` and it compiles and runs fine. Try posting a complete file which has the problem. Also the output of `cabal info dawg` may help (to check what version you are using).

Comment: Just posted the full dump here: http://pastebin.com/HPC47rNy. Perhaps my version of GHC is messed up? I go trying another one.

Comment: @doukremt With the full dump it still works for me. I have the same version `dawg`.

Comment: My suspicion would be that you have two versions of `binary` installed, and that `dawg` is compiled against another version than the one you end up using by default. You can figure out the one `dawg` is compiled against by saying `ghc-pkg describe dawg` and looking for version and hash in the `depends:` field. Similarly, you can check if `ghc-pkg describe binary` lists multiple versions of the `binary` package.

Comment: I just checked the hashes: they are identical. I also tried reinstalling the package, without effect. This is becoming frustrating :).

Comment: Well, you'd definitely have an instance of `binary` with a matching hash. The question is whether you also have another one. How many `binary` packages does `ghc-pkg list binary` show?

Comment: @kosmikus: Aha, it seems you got it! I have two versions `binary-0.5.1.1` and `binary-0.7.1.0`.

Comment: @kosmikus: I unregistered the old version following `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576868/how-can-i-uninstall-a-version-of-a-cabal-package` and it now works. Could you post an answer so that I can upvote you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem like this can be caused when two or more versions / instances of the same package are installed.

Package `dawg` might be compiled against a particular instance of the package `binary`, let's call it `binary-A`. It's possible you have a second instance of `binary`, `binary-B` installed as well. Now if GHCi decides to import `Data.Binary` from `binary-B`, then its `Binary` class will be considered different from the `Binary` class that `dawg` defines an instance for.

The solution is to explicitly select the correct `binary` instance, for example using the `-package-id` flag. If you use `cabal` for your project, then it will automatically try to resolve the dependencies for your project in such a way that consistent versions of all involved packages are selected.