# Could not find module `Control.Monad.State` after updating mtl

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I wanted to use the `Control.Monad.Except` module, but it turned out I had an outdated mtl package (It caused an import error - I had an obsolete module `Control.Monad.Error`). So I did

```
sudo cabal install mtl
```

And it installed the 2.2.2 version. However, now I had two versions installed, 2.1.2 and 2.2.2 which still caused an import error. I followed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10587933/2266261) and did

```
sudo ghc-pkg unregister --force mtl-2.1.2
```

to remove the old version. But now I get an error:

```
Could not find module `Control.Monad.State'
It is a member of the hidden package `monads-tf-0.1.0.2'.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

`ghc-pkg check` outputs

```
There are problems in package HTTP-4000.2.17:
  dependency "mtl-2.1.2-735d9c92b4f214d454fb5168bb1eb6ee" doesn't exist
There are problems in package fgl-5.5.0.1:
  dependency "mtl-2.1.2-735d9c92b4f214d454fb5168bb1eb6ee" doesn't exist
There are problems in package cgi-3001.1.8.5:
  dependency "mtl-2.1.2-735d9c92b4f214d454fb5168bb1eb6ee" doesn't exist
There are problems in package parsec-3.1.3:
  dependency "mtl-2.1.2-735d9c92b4f214d454fb5168bb1eb6ee" doesn't exist
There are problems in package regex-base-0.93.2:
  dependency "mtl-2.1.2-735d9c92b4f214d454fb5168bb1eb6ee" doesn't exist

The following packages are broken, either because they have a problem
listed above, or because they depend on a broken package.
HTTP-4000.2.17
fgl-5.5.0.1
cgi-3001.1.8.5
parsec-3.1.3
regex-base-0.93.2
network-2.4.1.2
regex-compat-0.95.1
regex-posix-0.95.2
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Is that the output of `ghc-pkg check` or `sudo ghc-pkg check`? (Is it talking about the global package database, or root's user-specific package database?) In the future, for day-to-day work, neither cabal nor ghc-pkg should need to be run with sudo powers; they're both capable of mucking about with a local package database that is user-specific, and this is generally safer (easier to nuke and restart fresh if something unrecoverable breaks).

Comment: @DanielWagner this comment actually led me to the solution - I shouldn't have used sudo, I did it out of habit (like with `pip` or `apt`). So the problem was that I installed mtl 2.2.2 for root and uninstalled 2.1.2 for local user. After doing `cabal install mtl-2.2.2` (no sudo) it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reinstall all the packages that depend on `mtl` to get them up to date with the new version. Cabal-install should be able to do that automatically if, in your project folder with the `yourproject.cabal` file, you do

```
$ cabal install --dependencies-only
```

As Daniel remarks, it may also be necessary to add `--reinstall`, namely if Cabal-install hasn't properly caught on to the dependency changes and needs to be manually ticked onto rebuilding them. If it thinks the reinstalls themselves might break yet other packages, `--force-reinstalls` may be needed too.

An alternative that avoids dependency hell is using the [new Nix-style commands](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build-overview.html), which never break anything when reinstalling.

Comment: You may also need `--reinstall`, depending on exactly what the solver thinks about what you've done behind its back.